# Environment.CurrentDirectory in C#.NET

Tags: c#-3.0

The property `Environment.CurrentDirectory` always returns the path of system directory instead my application directory. In my colleague's PC, it returns application directory.

What is the problem? How can I solve it?

The following code is working for me

```
ePCRSettings = XMLParser.XmlParser.Deserialize<PCRGeneratorSettings>(string.Format("{0}\\ePCRPDFSettings.xml", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory));

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory - Returns the directory E:\MyApplications\.
```

The following code is not working for me

```
ePCRSettings = XMLParser.XmlParser.Deserialize<PCRGeneratorSettings>(string.Format("{0}\\ePCRPDFSettings.xml", Environment.CurrentDirectory));

Environment.CurrentDirectory - Returns c:\windows\system32.
```

This .dll file can be used in VB 6 and ASP.NET applications

Comment: Add some more info... maybe a code snippet and explaining what you're trying to do would help you get an answer.

Comment: Is it a Windows Forms Application?

Comment: It is a class library. But can be used in VB 6 and ASP.NET applications

Answer (score 15):

set current directory

```
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory); //or set executing Assembly location path in param

Environment.CurrentDirectory //now returns your app path
```

Answer (score 7):

Use

System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be using the Environment.CurrentDirectory value as a base for file lookups because it can change and may not always be under your control. e.g. a File Save As to a different folder may change the 'current folder' value. As you can see it can yield unpredictable results.

Use a value that you can control better. e.g. a ResourcesFolderPath value in a configuration (xml?) file that is updated when you install your app.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that this could have something to do with the current user id that the app is running under, for example if you are running the app in a user session (e.g. debugging in VS) then this may return your current directory, but if you were running it under IIS then this could be why it is defaulting to the system folder?